# Supported Locales - ga_IE

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

while setting locale for google sheet api, throws the followinge error

Invalid requests[0].updateSpreadsheetProperties: Unsupported locale: ga_IE", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Reviewing the API doc, it seems to be not all locales are supported.

> The locale of the spreadsheet in one of the following formats:
>   an ISO 639-1 language code such as en
>   an ISO 639-2 language code such as fil, if no 639-1 code exists
>   a combination of the ISO language code and country code, such as en_US
>
> Note: when updating this field, not all locales/languages are supported.

Where can I find the list of supported locale?

Answer (score 0):

As you quotes over [Spreadsheet Properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#spreadsheetproperties), ISO 639-1 codes are preferred in first instance, ISO 639-2 are used when no ISO 639-1 exists, and, if no code exists for a given language on those ISOs, the combination of language_COUNTRY is used. This later case varies depending on the context. I assume that your code lays in any of the ISOs 639-1/2, so here you have the full lists:

**ISO 639-1**

```
Language    639-1 code
Abkhazian   ab
Afar    aa
Afrikaans   af
Akan    ak
Albanian    sq
Amharic am
Arabic  ar
Aragonese   an
Armenian    hy
Assamese    as
Avaric  av
Avestan ae
Aymara  ay
Azerbaijani az
Bambara bm
Bashkir ba
Basque  eu
Belarusian  be
Bengali bn
Bihari languages    bh
Bislama bi
Bosnian bs
Breton  br
Bulgarian   bg
Burmese my
Catalan, Valencian  ca
Chamorro    ch
Chechen ce
Chichewa, Chewa, Nyanja ny
Chinese zh
Chuvash cv
Cornish kw
Corsican    co
Cree    cr
Croatian    hr
Czech   cs
Danish  da
Divehi, Dhivehi, Maldivian  dv
Dutch, Flemish  nl
Dzongkha    dz
English en
Esperanto   eo
Estonian    et
Ewe ee
Faroese fo
Fijian  fj
Finnish fi
French  fr
Fulah   ff
Galician    gl
Georgian    ka
German  de
Greek, Modern (1453-)   el
Guarani gn
Gujarati    gu
Haitian, Haitian Creole ht
Hausa   ha
Hebrew  he
Herero  hz
Hindi   hi
Hiri Motu   ho
Hungarian   hu
Interlingua(International Auxiliary Language Association)   ia
Indonesian  id
Interlingue, Occidental ie
Irish   ga
Igbo    ig
Inupiaq ik
Ido io
Icelandic   is
Italian it
Inuktitut   iu
Japanese    ja
Javanese    jv
Kalaallisut, Greenlandic    kl
Kannada kn
Kanuri  kr
Kashmiri    ks
Kazakh  kk
Central Khmer   km
Kikuyu, Gikuyu  ki
Kinyarwanda rw
Kirghiz, Kyrgyz ky
Komi    kv
Kongo   kg
Korean  ko
Kurdish ku
Kuanyama, Kwanyama  kj
Latin   la
Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch    lb
Ganda   lg
Limburgan, Limburger, Limburgish    li
Lingala ln
Lao lo
Lithuanian  lt
Luba-Katanga    lu
Latvian lv
Manx    gv
Macedonian  mk
Malagasy    mg
Malay   ms
Malayalam   ml
Maltese mt
Maori   mi
Marathi mr
Marshallese mh
Mongolian   mn
Nauru   na
Navajo, Navaho  nv
North Ndebele   nd
Nepali  ne
Ndonga  ng
Norwegian Bokmål    nb
Norwegian Nynorsk   nn
Norwegian   no
Sichuan Yi, Nuosu   ii
South Ndebele   nr
Occitan oc
Ojibwa  oj
Church Slavic, Old Slavonic, Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian,Old Church Slavonic cu
Oromo   om
Oriya   or
Ossetian, Ossetic   os
Punjabi, Panjabi    pa
Pali    pi
Persian fa
Polish  pl
Pashto, Pushto  ps
Portuguese  pt
Quechua qu
Romansh rm
Rundi   rn
Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan   ro
Russian ru
Sanskrit    sa
Sardinian   sc
Sindhi  sd
Northern Sami   se
Samoan  sm
Sango   sg
Serbian sr
Gaelic, Scottish Gaelic gd
Shona   sn
Sinhala, Sinhalese  si
Slovak  sk
Slovenian   sl
Somali  so
Southern Sotho  st
Spanish, Castilian  es
Sundanese   su
Swahili sw
Swati   ss
Swedish sv
Tamil   ta
Telugu  te
Tajik   tg
Thai    th
Tigrinya    ti
Tibetan bo
Turkmen tk
Tagalog tl
Tswana  tn
Tonga(Tonga Islands)    to
Turkish tr
Tsonga  ts
Tatar   tt
Twi tw
Tahitian    ty
Uighur, Uyghur  ug
Ukrainian   uk
Urdu    ur
Uzbek   uz
Venda   ve
Vietnamese  vi
Volapük vo
Walloon wa
Welsh   cy
Wolof   wo
Western Frisian fy
Xhosa   xh
Yiddish yi
Yoruba  yo
Zhuang, Chuang  za
Zulu    zu
```

**ISO 639-2 not covered by ISO 639-1**

```
Language    ISO 639-2
Achinese    ace
Acoli   ach
Adangme ada
Adyghe; Adygei  ady
Afro-Asiatic languages  afa
Afrihili    afh
Ainu    ain
Akkadian    akk
Aleut   ale
Algonquian languages    alg
Southern Altai  alt
English, Old(ca.450–1100)   ang
Angika  anp
Apache languages    apa
Official Aramaic(700–300 BCE);Imperial Aramaic(700–300 BCE) arc
Mapudungun;Mapuche  arn
Arapaho arp
Artificial languages    art
Arawak  arw
Asturian;Bable;Leonese;Asturleonese ast
Athapascan languages    ath
Australian languages    aus
Awadhi  awa
Banda languages bad
Bamileke languages  bai
Baluchi bal
Balinese    ban
Basa    bas
Baltic languages    bat
Beja;Bedawiyet  bej
Bemba   bem
Berber languages    ber
Bhojpuri    bho
Bikol   bik
Bini;Edo    bin
Siksika bla
Bantu (Other)   bnt
Braj    bra
Batak languages btk
Buriat  bua
Buginese    bug
Blin; Bilin byn
Caddo   cad
Central American Indian languages   cai
Galibi Carib    car
Caucasian languages cau
Cebuano ceb
Celtic languages    cel
Chibcha chb
Chagatai    chg
Chuukese    chk
Mari    chm
Chinook jargon  chn
Choctaw cho
Chipewyan;Dene Suline   chp
Cherokee    chr
Cheyenne    chy
Chamic languages    cmc
Montenegrin cnr
Coptic  cop
Creolesandpidgins, English based    cpe
Creolesand pidgins, French-based    cpf
Creolesand pidgins, Portuguese-based    cpp
Crimean Tatar;Crimean Turkish   crh
Creolesandpidgins   crp
Kashubian   csb
Cushitic languages  cus
Dakota  dak
Dargwa  dar
Land Dayak languages    day
Delaware    del
Slave (Athapascan)  den
Dogrib  dgr
Dinka   din
Dogri   doi
Dravidian languages dra
Lower Sorbian   dsb
Duala   dua
Dutch, Middle(ca. 1050–1350)    dum
Dyula   dyu
Efik    efi
Egyptian (Ancient)  egy
Ekajuk  eka
Elamite elx
English, Middle(1100–1500)  enm
Ewondo  ewo
Fang    fan
Fanti   fat
Filipino;Pilipino   fil
Finno-Ugrian languages  fiu
Fon fon
French, Middle(ca. 1400–1600)   frm
French, Old(842–ca. 1400)   fro
Northern Frisian    frr
Eastern Frisian frs
Friulian    fur
Ga  gaa
Gayo    gay
Gbaya   gba
Germanic languages  gem
Geez    gez
Gilbertese  gil
German, Middle High(ca. 1050–1500)  gmh
German, Old High(ca. 750–1050)  goh
Gondi   gon
Gorontalo   gor
Gothic  got
Grebo   grb
Greek, Ancient(to 1453) grc
Swiss German;Alemannic;Alsatian gsw
Gwich'in    gwi
Haida   hai
Hawaiian    haw
Hiligaynon  hil
Himachali languages; Pahari languages   him
Hittite hit
Hmong;Mong  hmn
Upper Sorbian   hsb
Hupa    hup
Iban    iba
Ijo languages   ijo
Iloko   ilo
Indic languages inc
Indo-European languages ine
Ingush  inh
Iranian languages   ira
Iroquoian languages iro
Lojban  jbo
Judeo-Persian   jpr
Judeo-Arabic    jrb
Kara-Kalpak kaa
Kabyle  kab
Kachin;Jingpho  kac
Kamba   kam
Karen languages kar
Kawi    kaw
Kabardian   kbd
Khasi   kha
Khoisan languages   khi
Khotanese;Sakan kho
Kimbundu    kmb
Konkani kok
Kosraean    kos
Kpelle  kpe
Karachay-Balkar krc
Karelian    krl
Kru languages   kro
Kurukh  kru
Kumyk   kum
Kutenai kut
Ladino  lad
Lahnda  lah
Lamba   lam
Lezghian    lez
Mongo   lol
Lozi    loz
Luba-Lulua  lua
Luiseno lui
Lunda   lun
Luo (Kenya and Tanzania)    luo
Lushai  lus
Madurese    mad
Magahi  mag
Maithili    mai
Makasar mak
Mandingo    man
Austronesian languages  map
Masai   mas
Moksha  mdf
Mandar  mdr
Mende   men
Irish, Middle(900–1200) mga
Mi'kmaq;Micmac  mic
Minangkabau min
Uncoded languages   mis
Mon-Khmer languages mkh
Manchu  mnc
Manipuri    mni
Manobo languages    mno
Mohawk  moh
Mossi   mos
Multiple languages  mul
Munda languages mun
Creek   mus
Mirandese   mwl
Marwari mwr
Mayan languages myn
Erzya   myv
Nahuatl languages   nah
North American Indian languages nai
Neapolitan  nap
Low German; Low Saxon; German, Low; Saxon, Low  nds
Nepal Bhasa;Newari  new
Nias    nia
Niger-Kordofanian languages nic
Niuean  niu
Nogai   nog
Norse, Old  non
N'Ko    nqo
Pedi;Sepedi;Northern Sotho  nso
Nubian languages    nub
Classical Newari;Old Newari;Classical Nepal Bhasa   nwc
Nyamwezi    nym
Nyankole    nyn
Nyoro   nyo
Nzima   nzi
Osage   osa
Turkish, Ottoman(1500–1928) ota
Otomian languages   oto
Papuan languages    paa
Pangasinan  pag
Pahlavi pal
Pampanga;Kapampangan    pam
Papiamento  pap
Palauan pau
Persian, Old(ca. 600–400 B.C.)  peo
Philippine languages    phi
Phoenician  phn
Pohnpeian   pon
Prakrit languages   pra
Provençal, Old(to 1500);Old Occitan (to 1500)   pro
Reserved for local use  qaa-qtz
Rajasthani  raj
Rapanui rap
Rarotongan;Cook Islands Maori   rar
Romance languages   roa
Romany  rom
Aromanian;Arumanian;Macedo-Romanian rup
Sandawe sad
Yakut   sah
South American Indian (Other)   sai
Salishan languages  sal
Samaritan Aramaic   sam
Sasak   sas
Santali sat
Sicilian    scn
Scots   sco
Selkup  sel
Semitic languages   sem
Irish, Old(to 900)  sga
Sign Languages  sgn
Shan    shn
Sidamo  sid
Siouan languages    sio
Sino-Tibetan languages  sit
Slavic languages    sla
Southern Sami   sma
Sami languages  smi
Lule Sami   smj
Inari Sami  smn
Skolt Sami  sms
Soninke snk
Sogdian sog
Songhai languages   son
Sranan Tongo    srn
Serer   srr
Nilo-Saharan languages  ssa
Sukuma  suk
Susu    sus
Sumerian    sux
Classical Syriac    syc
Syriac  syr
Tai languages   tai
Timne   tem
Tereno  ter
Tetum   tet
Tigre   tig
Tiv tiv
Tokelau tkl
Klingon;tlhIngan-Hol    tlh
Tlingit tli
Tamashek    tmh
Tonga (Nyasa)   tog
Tok Pisin   tpi
Tsimshian   tsi
Tumbuka tum
Tupi languages  tup
Altaic languages    tut
Tuvalu  tvl
Tuvinian    tyv
Udmurt  udm
Ugaritic    uga
Umbundu umb
Undetermined    und
Vai vai
Votic   vot
Wakashan languages  wak
Walamo  wal
Waray   war
Washo   was
Sorbian languages   wen
Kalmyk;Oirat    xal
Yao yao
Yapese  yap
Yupik languages ypk
Zapotec zap
Blissymbols;Blissymbolics;Bliss zbl
Zenaga  zen
Standard Moroccan Tamazight zgh
Zande languages znd
Zuni    zun
No linguistic content; Not applicable   zxx
Zaza;Dimili;Dimli;Kirdki;Kirmanjki;Zazaki   zza
```

Just for clarification: you can see the full list of ISO 639 codes on the [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). As I said before, I assume that your language is one of the former. If that is not the case, please ask for further help so I can assist you better.

Comment: as mentioned in my question: 'ga_IE' is the one that failed but is in this list. I had checked this ISO codes earlier. I feel Google API has it's own set, which is what i'm looking for.

Comment: I will assume that by `ga_IE` you mean *Irish from Ireland*. In that case, you should just use the code `ga`. As you can see on ISO 639-1, that former code is the one used for modern day Irish. Let me know if that solves your situation.

Comment: `ga` also is not supported. I just verified it.

Comment: Hi there @Swarup, I deeply investigated your issue and this looks like a Sheets bug. I have created a Issue Tracker case, you can visit it to check for updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143132389